# Run multiple CakePHP project on NGINX server

Tags: php, nginx, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, nginx-config

I have two projects which are built-in CakePHP with different CakePHP version.
project1 that is built in CakePHP 2 and project2 is built-in CakePHP 3, now I want to host these 2 applications on the same server which runs on the NGINX.

```
  /var/www/html/ (project1 is placed on the root directory.)
            bin/
            config/
            logs/
            plugins/
            src/
            tests/
            tmp/
            vendor/
            webroot/
            cake_2_0/ ( <== this is project2)
                app/
                lib/
                plugins/
                vendors/
                .htaccess
                index.php
                README
            .gitignore
            .htaccess
            .travis.yml
            composer.json
            index.php
            phpunit.xml.dist
            README.md
```

I have followed the CakePHP documentation and successfully set up the project1 which runs on CakePHP 3 https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/installation.html#nginx

Configuration file of Project1:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen   [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/webroot;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;

        access_log /var/www/html/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/html/error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Project 1 runs successfully, but I'm getting 404 error when I run project2 like
http://project1/project2 ( 404 error)

Comment: With your configuration, you said that folder which should render files are in `/var/www/html/webroot`. Or the folder `project2` is outside. So you have two solutions. 1- You create a new configuration for `project2` which will be similar. 2- You add a [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to change the root folder if the route match `/project2`.

Comment: I am pretty certain you cannot place a Cake project inside another one, since they rely on URL rewriting. However, you can still accomplish the same result with some clever routing from the server. So place both projects next to each other: `/var/www/html/{project1,project2}` and now bind the URL `project1/project2/` the directory of project 2. (But I don't know how to do that :p)